# Dart style guidance

Tags: dart

I am trying to follow the dart style guide for my dart code but I am unsure about this:

```dart
library ch_panel.section_model;

import 'package:ch_padart/models/page.dart';

class Section {

  String icon;
  String title;
  List<Page> pages;

  Section(this.icon, this.title, this.pages);
  Section.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json): this(json['icon'], json['title'], parsePages(json['pages']));

  static List<Page> parsePages(List<Map> pageJson) {
    List<Page> itemPages = new List();

    pageJson.forEach((v) {
      itemPages.add(new Page(v['icon'], v['title']));
    });

    return itemPages;
  }
}
```

Style guide I am referring to:
https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/#members

Can you re-do this code as an example of the correct use of style in this case?

Comment: What are you in doubt about?

Comment: I am unsure if I should be using a static function in a constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by "static function in a constructor". It is preferable to use a constructor *instead* of a static method. It's fine in your code.

Comment: I know this. But in this case I call pastePages() in the constructor. Is there a "more correct" way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried https://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with using a static function in a constructor initializer list. If the function isn't used anywhere else, and users are not expected to use it, I'd make it private, but otherwise I'd have no problem submitting this code.

Comment: If you don't need the `parsePages` method for anything other than constructing I would probably move the code into the `fromJson` constructor, but if you do I see no problem with having it.

I would also use a list literal `[]` instead of calling the `List` constructor. And if going deeper I would rewrite that `forEach` + adding to a list into mapping over `pageJson`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What can be improved is the formatting. Dartformat does this automatically (should be integrated in DartEditor). You can also run it manually from command line.

```bash
# install
pub global activate dart_style
# run 
pub global run dartformat -w myfile.dart
# or to format a whole directory incl subdirs
pub global run dartformat -w .
```

```dart
library ch_panel.section_model;

import 'package:ch_padart/models/page.dart';

class Section {
  String icon;
  String title;
  List<Page> pages;

  Section(this.icon, this.title, this.pages);
  Section.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : this(json['icon'], json['title'], parsePages(json['pages']));

  static List<Page> parsePages(List<Map> pageJson) {
    List<Page> itemPages = new List();

    pageJson.forEach((v) {
      itemPages.add(new Page(v['icon'], v['title']));
    });

    return itemPages;
  }
}
```

There is also a linter work in progress which checks style violations  (very early stage but can already be used)

```bash
 # install
 pub global activate -s git git@github.com:dart-lang/linter.git
 # run
 pub global run linter myfile.dart
```

Comment: I can't find the linter on pub

Comment: You are right. I tried it on my PC and the output didn't look like an error message and because I had it already installed running it worked. I updated my answer.